# How to create label text using html helper from Model in ASP.Net MVC 5 (Razor View)

Tags: asp.net-ajax, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I am trying to create a label text using html helper from my model RoomAvailabilitySummary

**View Design:**

```
@model IEnumerable<WBE.Model.RoomAvailabilitySummary>

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("RoomsAvail", new AjaxOptions
                                       {
                                        UpdateTargetId = "RoomsAvailData",
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                                       }))
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <div class="container paddingzero">
    <div class="row rowbackground">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ARRDAT)
    </div>
    <div class="row rowbackground">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ARRDAT)
    </div>
    <div class="row rowbackground">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DEPDAT)
    </div>
    <div class="row rowbackground">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DEPDAT)
    </div>
 </div>
}
<div class="tab-content" id="RoomsAvailData">
    @Html.Partial("_AvailableRoomsandPackages", Model);
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class RoomAvailabilitySummary
{
    [Key]
    public int CUSTCODE { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Checkin")]
    public string ARRDAT { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Check out")]
    public string DEPDAT { get; set; }
}
```

Problem: I am unable to create label text using my model with html helper.

Error i am getting:
   **IEnumerable' 
   does not contain a definition for 'ARRDAT' and no 
   extension method 'ARRDAT' accepting a first argument 
   of type IEnumerable**

What i have done the mistake  in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the following changes in my design and its working as expected.

```
@Html.Partial("_BookingInputs")                 
<div class="tab-content" id="RoomsAvailData">
 @Html.Action("AvailableInventory", "Bookings"); 
</div>
<div id="Loading" class="Loading">
</div>
```